# How can I get the free hours of a table in database?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has starthour, endhour and date.
What I need is to display by sql query the free hours available and the time range of the same, depending on the date.

The query only show the free hours not occupied.
The output on the screen would look something like this

```
Date : 01/08/2017  starhour : 20:00 endhour : 21:00 duration : 60
```

Here is what I have done so far:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT date, starthour, endhour 
       FROM diary 
       WHERE diary_id = 1025 
       AND date = TO_DATE('2017-05-01','yyyy/MM/dd') 
       AND ( starthour >= to_timestamp('11:00:00.01','HH24:MI:SS.FF') 
         AND endhour <= to_timestamp('11:15:00.01','HH24:MI:SS.FF')
           ) 
    ) ORDER BY date ASC, starthour ASC
```

Comment: ,Post your sample data and expected output.

Comment: And also what you tried so far.

Comment: SELECT
        *
    FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                date,
                starthour,
                endhour
            FROM
                diary
            WHERE
                diary_id = 1025
            AND
                date = TO_DATE('2017-05-01','yyyy/MM/dd')
            AND (
                    starthour >= to_timestamp('11:00:00.01','HH24:MI:SS.FF')
                AND
                    endhour <= to_timestamp('11:15:00.01','HH24:MI:SS.FF')
            )
        )
    ORDER BY
        date ASC,
        starthour ASC;

Comment: Why... why have `starthour`, `endhour` **AND** `date`? Why not just have two `DATE` type columns `starthour` and `endhour`? A `DATE` datatype has a time component and would make things so much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE diary ( "DATE", starthour, endhour ) AS
  SELECT DATE '2017-04-10', '12:00', '12:15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2017-04-10', '12:15', '12:30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Immediately follows
  SELECT DATE '2017-04-10', '12:45', '13:15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2017-04-10', '13:00', '14:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Partly overlaps
  SELECT DATE '2017-04-10', '14:30', '15:30' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2017-04-10', '14:45', '15:15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Inside previous
  SELECT DATE '2017-04-10', '16:00', '17:00' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
WITH dates ( starthour, endhour ) AS (
  -- Convert your dates to include time components.

  SELECT "DATE" + TO_DATE( starthour, 'HH24:MI' ) - TO_DATE( '00:00', 'HH24:MI' ) ),
         "DATE" + TO_DATE( endhour,   'HH24:MI' ) - TO_DATE( '00:00', 'HH24:MI' ) )
  FROM   diary
  WHERE  "DATE" + TO_DATE( starthour, 'HH24:MI' ) - TO_DATE( '00:00', 'HH24:MI' ) )
           < :your_end_date
  AND    "DATE" + TO_DATE( endhour,   'HH24:MI' ) - TO_DATE( '00:00', 'HH24:MI' ) )
           > :your_start_date

  -- Add zero width entries at the start and end of the range:

  UNION ALL SELECT :your_start_date, :your_start_date FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL SELECT :your_end_date,   :your_end_date   FROM DUAL
),
unpivoted ( datetime, isStartEnd, cnt ) AS (
  -- Convert pairs of start/end times to a list of times
  -- where the start of an appointment has a corresponding value of +1 and the
  -- end of an appointment has a corresponding value of -1. The CNT column
  -- is the total of all the previous +1 / -1 values.

  SELECT datetime,
         isStartEnd,
         SUM( isStartEnd ) OVER ( ORDER BY datetime ASC, isStartEnd DESC )
  FROM   dates
  UNPIVOT ( datetime FOR isStartEnd IN ( starthour AS 1, endhour AS -1 ) )
),
appointment_bounds ( startdate, enddate, isStartEnd ) AS (
  SELECT LAG( datetime, 1 ) OVER ( ORDER BY datetime ASC, isStartEnd DESC ),
         datetime,
         isStartEnd
  FROM   unpivoted
  WHERE  ( cnt = 0 AND isStartEnd = -1 ) -- Last time in a group of appointments
  OR     ( cnt = 1 AND isStartEnd =  1 ) -- First time in a group of appointments
)
SELECT startdate,
       enddate
FROM   appointment_bounds
WHERE  isStartEnd = 1
AND    startdate IS NOT NULL;
```

**Output**:

Running the above query with the bind parameters `:your_start_date` and `:your_end_date` as `2017-04-10 11:00:00` and `2017-04-10 16:30:00` respectively:

```
STARTDATE           ENDDATE
------------------- -------------------
2017-04-10 11:00:00 2017-04-10 12:00:00
2017-04-10 12:30:00 2017-04-10 12:45:00
2017-04-10 14:00:00 2017-04-10 14:30:00
2017-04-10 15:30:00 2017-04-10 16:00:00
```

**Simpler Query**:

```
WITH dates ( starthour, endhour ) AS (
  -- Convert your dates to include time components.

  SELECT "DATE" + TO_DATE( starthour, 'HH24:MI' ) - TO_DATE( '00:00', 'HH24:MI' ) ),
         "DATE" + TO_DATE( endhour,   'HH24:MI' ) - TO_DATE( '00:00', 'HH24:MI' ) )
  FROM   diary
  WHERE  "DATE" + TO_DATE( starthour, 'HH24:MI' ) - TO_DATE( '00:00', 'HH24:MI' ) )
           < :your_end_date
  AND    "DATE" + TO_DATE( endhour,   'HH24:MI' ) - TO_DATE( '00:00', 'HH24:MI' ) )
           > :your_start_date

  -- Add zero width entries at the start and end of the range:

  UNION ALL SELECT :your_start_date, :your_start_date FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL SELECT :your_end_date,   :your_end_date   FROM DUAL
)
SELECT prev_endhour, starthour
FROM   (
  SELECT LAG( endhour ) OVER ( ORDER BY starthour ASC, endhour ASC ) AS prev_endhour,
         starthour
  FROM   dates
)
WHERE prev_endhour < starthour;
```